# Quiero hacer que un div no se muestre al recargar la página (verificación de edad)

Tags: javascript, html

quiero que al recargar el sitio web no muestre un div, pero al mismo tiempo que borre un hidden del div home_2 al recargar la página, esto es con la finalidad de hacer una verificación de edad y que cuando recargue o vuelva al sitio ya no le aparezca el mensaje

```
$(".LangHref").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if ($('.Edad-seleccion').remove()) {
           $('.home_2').removeClass('hidden');
           comenzar();
         return false;
       } else {
       }
   });
```

```
<div class="Edad-seleccion">
               <center><img src="images/logo.png" class="cara-2 cara" width="375px"></center>
           <div class="info-age">
               <p class="text">¿Eres mayor de edad?</p>
               <p class="text">You're of age?</p>
               <div class="buttons-to-choose">
                   <a href="#" class="LangHref"><button onclick="AcceptEdad()" class="button-choose">Si</button></a> <a href="#"><button id="no"  class="button-choose">No</button></a>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
 <!--HEADER-->
<div id="wrapper" class="home_2 hidden">
 <header id="header"> 
   <!-- Navigation Row Start -->
   <div class="top-bar">
     <div class="container"> 
       <div class="top-social">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="">/ENGLISH</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres entonces que esa validación permanezca aunque el usuario recargue el navegador?

Comment: No, quiero que se quite.

Answer (score -1):

Antes de darte la respuesta te sugiero que mejores la arquitectura de tu codigo para que este más ordenado y el naming de tus clases sean mas apropiado. Que desorden.

Lo que tu quieres es que el usuario cuando ingresa a la web confirme que sea mayor de edad y luego no aparezca más el mensaje de verificación.

Para esto tienes que crear una cookie al cliente. Una vez el usuario presione que es mayor de edad se crea la cookie

Luego creas una función que se ejecute inmediatamente se acceda a la web que valide si existe la cookie. Si existe el usuario no vera el mensaje preguntando si es mayor de edad.

Te dejo este link:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Un bloqueador de cookies deja este planteamiento totalmente inutilizado.